# Creating html with javascript the right way

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

So i've created a function that builds and returns .html (as a big string) file based on dynamic vars it receives.
I feel like this is not the proper way to do so. I would like the html file to be a template but i don't know how to set it up. I'm using gruntjs. So maybe it could be done with a grunt plugin that runs a task. Any ideas on how to do this more properly?

```
function createHtml(size) {
    var w = size[0] + "px";
    var h = size[1] + "px";

    var html =
      '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><title>Document</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/retina_sprite.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/sprite.min.css"><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script><script src="./js/banner.min.js"></script><style>body{margin:0;padding:0;}#wrapper{position: relative; overflow:hidden;width:' +
      w +
      ";height:" +
      h +
      ';}</style></head><body onload="bannerInit()";><div id="wrapper"></div></body></html>';

    var n = html.search('<div id="wrapper">') + 18;
    var allDivs = "";

    for (var i = json.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var id = Object.keys(json[i]).toString();
      id = id.replace("#", "");
      var div = "<div id=" + id + " class=icon-" + id + "></div>";
      allDivs += div;
    }

    var result = html.splice(n, 0, allDivs); // inserts divs in <div id="wrapper">
    return result;
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=grunt+html+template+plugin

Comment: I’m not sure how we can answer this. “I feel like this is not the proper way”, why?